# Azure - Access token request with a certificate - postman

Tags: azure, postman, azure-keyvault

i want to test access to key vault using certificate
**Scenario**
Second case: Access token request with a certificate
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

I am struggling to supply

> client_assertion

An assertion (a JSON web token) that you need to create and sign with the certificate you registered as credentials for your application. Read about certificate credentials to learn how to register your certificate and the format of the assertion.

I dont know why powershell has to bes used, and I dont have pfx, so cant use
https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/10/how-to-use-postman-to-perform-a-client-credentials-grant-flow-with-a-certificate/

Is it possible to generate signed JWT using postman?

Note: Certificates in postman added. so that part is taken care

Comment: Of course  can use postman to get the token.

Comment: sure there will be. Please elaborate with steps

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can generate `client_assertion` directly in postman, please use the script below to create a self-assigned certificate, then you can use the [script you mentioned](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/10/how-to-use-postman-to-perform-a-client-credentials-grant-flow-with-a-certificate/) to get the token.

```
$certroopath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop"
$certname = "mycert1"
$certpassword = "P@ssw0rd1234"

$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "$certname" -CertStoreLocation cert:\CurrentUser\My
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $certpassword -Force -AsPlainText
$certwithThumb = "cert:\CurrentUser\my\"+$cert.Thumbprint
$filepath = "$certroopath\$certname.pfx"
Export-PfxCertificate -cert $certwithThumb -FilePath $filepath -Password $pwd
```